# How to research API usage?

Tags: javascript, research

I'd like to find out how often and if a certain pattern in a certain programming language is used.

In my case - I'd like to find out how many/if people do `eval("/"+regexString+"/")` in JavaScript and/or compose regular expressions from strings using `/`.

Typically, I perform a GitHub search - I did this when [working on a feature in the past](https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/0237932cee84712951a2#statistics), and it was for a much smaller API with a clear function call and a smaller scoped use case - doing this manually doesn't seem practical here.

I'm doing this in order to characterise an API I'm working on and I'm considering whether or not this is something people do in order to provide a better and more consistent API..

---

- How can I research how common this pattern is?

(I'd appreciate answers based on science and known practices)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to search for *Javascript [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools* (like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/534601/841108)), e.g. [Flow](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1505962329687926/flow-a-new-static-type-checker-for-javascript/). You'll find many research papers on that subject.

<sup>I've heard several talks on that subject, and IIRC `eval`  is used, sometimes carelessly or needlessly, in many practical Javascript software.</sup>

Your question can be understood in two different ways:

How often is `eval("/"+regexString+"/")` *statically appearing* in various Javascript source code?

How often is `eval("/"+regexString+"/")` *dynamically executed* in some given application?

You could hack some existing Javascript implementation to detect such patterns.

Notice that if `regexString` is a single line string starting with a `/`  character,  `eval("/"+regexString+"/")` is evaluating a comment!

Don't forget the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) & [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem); hence, static program analysis can never be entirely satisfactory.